# Gatling/Scala is unable to find JSON retrieved session key

Tags: json, scala, jsonpath, gatling

I am very new to Gatling and being half made to use it I need to write automation scripts with it. I have no prior experience with it in any way.

When I am trying to run multiple scenarios I retrieve a "session_key" as part of a JSON response after a login. I tried to follow guides from the internet, saved this value but when I attempt to use it further in my second scenario the Expression Language can't find it.

I have verified my JSONPath expression for it and it seems to be correct.

```
{"result":1,"resultType":"ack","output":{"session_key":"a value for the session key goes here"},"errorMessage":false,"errorCode":false,"additional":{"locationtabs":["tab 1","tab 2","tab 3"]}}
```

I have also listed my code below but replaced usage data with mock data for my question.

```
package basic

import com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.Predef._
import com.excilys.ebi.gatling.http.Predef._
import com.excilys.ebi.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import com.excilys.ebi.gatling.http.Headers.Names._
import com.jayway.jsonpath._
import akka.util.duration._
import bootstrap._

class GetLocations extends Simulation
{


    val httpConf = httpConfig
        .baseURL("https://myURL")
        .acceptCharsetHeader("ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7")
        .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
        .disableFollowRedirect

    val scn = scenario("Login Test")
        .exec(
            http("requestLogin")
            .post("/restapi/login")
            .param("username", "a username")
            .param("password", "a password")
            .param("client_uid", "testUid")
            .check(jsonPath("$.result").is("1"))
            .check(jsonPath("$.output.session_key").findAll.saveAs("session_key"))

        ).pause(15)



    val getLocations = scenario("Get Locations")
        .exec(
            http("getLocations")
            .post("/restapi/get_employee_favouritelocations")
            .param("client_uid","testUid")
            .param("clientType","automatedTest")
            .param("session_key","${session_key}")
            .check(jsonPath("$.result").is("1"))
        )

    setUp(scn.users(50).ramp(50).protocolConfig(httpConf),
          getLocations.users(50).ramp(50).protocolConfig(httpConf)
        )

}
```

Any help you can provide is appreciated as this has been giving me headaches for a week and unfortunately only i am available to work with this currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different scenarios, where one has its users save some data into their session, and the other one has its users trying to fetch data from their session.

Those are different virtual users, so you're not saving and fetching from the same place.

Basically, you're doing it wrong.
It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.